# Restarting a python tcpserver based on sockerserver library

Tags: python, sockets

Working with a tcp server - following snippet creates the server

```
import threading
import socketserver
import time

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    #def __init__(self, a,b,c):
    #    super().__init__(request=a,client_address=b,server=c)

    def setup(self):
        pass

    def handle(self):
        pass

    def finish(self):
        pass

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

class Transport_Server:
    def __init__(self):

        # Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
        HOST, PORT = "0.0.0.0", 5001

        self.server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
        #with self.server:
        ip, port = self.server.server_address

        self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)

        # Exit the server thread when the main thread terminates
        self.server_thread.daemon = True
        self.server_thread.start()
        print("Server loop running in thread:", self.server_thread.name)


    def shutdown(self):
        self.server.shutdown()
        self.server_thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":


    transport = Transport_Server()

    print("Server started")
    time.sleep(5)
    
    print("Shutting down")
    transport.shutdown()

    print("Waiting")
    time.sleep(5)

    transport = Transport_Server()

    print("Server restarted")
```

Works fine.

But if I shutdown the server with `object.server.shutdown()` and then create a new instance of `Transport_Server`

I get

```
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a server is closed, the connection will not come to 'CLOSED' state immediately. instead, it will be in 'TIME_WAIT' state. to allow the client receive 'FIN_ACK' packet and to ttl down all delayed incoming packets.

During this 'TIME_WAIT' duration, we can't create new server in that address.

More details here: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt

---

Checking the newly posted code above, `server.shutdown()` is just not enough, if you are restarting the server again immediately. as it just tells the `serve_forever()` to stop. but the ip address and port occupied stays in listening state.
when we add `server.server_close()` it cleans up the server and releasing the address, making it ready for a restart.

You can find the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.shutdown).

Below the updated `Transport_Server.shutdown()` function, which works fine.

```py
def shutdown(self):
    self.server.shutdown()
    self.server_thread.join()
    self.server.server_close()
```

Comment: I suspected something like that and I did a sleep for 5 seconds and it still didn't work - any ideas what a good value on Windows is?

Comment: Its 4 mins by default. which twice of MSL. check this question in microsoft doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/230227/time-wait-from-netstat.html

Comment: It seems to be way more than 4 mins. I'm just resetting and restarting the server - is there any way to disable this?

Comment: In windows check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance) to change this duration.

Comment: Or just try closing connection from client instead. and then terminate the server.

Comment: I changed the value of TcpTimedWaitDelay to 2 - i assume the units are seconds. I restarted the PC. Waited for 10 seconds between shutdown and restart and same error message.

Comment: Can you try `netstat` command to check current connection state and what process using that port ?

Comment: It doesn't display that port being used - I know the server code works. Interestingly, if I control-c the program and restart - I can open the server socket. it's when I shutdown(), sleep and then recreate the instance that doesn't work.

Comment: Ah.. looks like when you `shutdown()` it stops only main thread. but another thread still running and using the port. so the process did not terminate fully. when you do ctrl+c it terminated the process completely(including all threads) and released the address..

Comment: Actually shutdown() does terminate the worker thread. I edited my OP to add that code - I wait for the worker thread to terminate and it does. I assume the server socket is closed. Looking at the Python `socketserver` code, there's a `with` around the socket - so I'm assuming it's being closed.

Comment: Getting back to your netstat suggestion, yes that port is used is there while I sleep before the shutdown and after the shutdown. but when the program terminates by itself - it's gone. So looks like when the shutdown() is called, it's not closing the server socket.

Comment: Actually isn't that the opposite. Anyways shutdown() does close that thread down - I checked it because I called child_thread.join(). I'm not terminating the main thread - it's running.

Comment: I reedited my OP code - that's the full code to test in Python3. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Works as long as there's no active clients. If there is, it hangs in the server_close() function. I think the main cause of the issue is that in my ThreadedTCPRequestHandler's handler() method - I'm in a loop handling the client connection. Is handler() called once per client connection or every few time slices. Doc is not clear

Comment: The solution seems to be to call `self.server.block_on_close = False` after construction of the server. From the docs `If true, server_close() waits until all non-daemonic threads terminate.`